# Average customer spending at each month and number of ordered items at each month

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have 4 tables:

```
CUSTOMER (idCustomer,name,phone,email, markdown)
ORDER (idOrder,day,Customer_idCustomer)
ORDERITEM (idOrderItem, quantity, Order_idOrder, Product_idProduct)
PRODUCT (idProduct,name,price,description).
```

What would be the query for:

1. Average customer spending (for each customer) in individual months
2. Number of ordered items?

I already wrote some queries on this database.
Since I do it for Java application with JDBC, maybe I can split these two queries and make calculation of average separately but what is the best approach? Is there a way how to do it just with two SQL queries?

Thank you for help.

Query I use for price reduction:

```
String sql = "SELECT c.markdown, SUM(oi.quantity * p.price) 
FROM orderitem oi, `order` o, product p, customer c 
WHERE c.idCustomer = o.Customer_idCustomer 
AND oi.Order_idOrder=o.idOrder 
AND oi.Product_idProduct=p.idProduct 
AND o.idOrder=" + idOrderValue + " 
GROUP BY oi.Order_idOrder";
```

[Look here for database design (ERD)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGh0e.png)

Comment: Also please format your current query so that it is readable.  One line queries can't be read easily, which means we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an aggregation query with `JOIN`s.  Use proper `JOIN` syntax!  Do not use commas in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT year(o.day) as yyyy,
       month(o.day) as mm,
       SUM(oi.quantity * p.price) / COUNT(DISTINCT c.idCustomer) as avg_customer_spending,
       SUM(oi.quantity) as num_items
FROM customers c JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.idCustomer = o.Customer_idCustomer JOIN
     orderitem oi
     ON oi.Order_idOrder = o.idOrder JOIN
     product p
     ON oi.Product_idProduct = p.idProduct 
GROUP BY year(o.day), month(o.day);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for very fast response. It seems to work great.